# Stop Jupyter Notebook widget results from displaying?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a function that takes in a variable from a slider widget in a jupyter notebook, does some computation, and returns a dataframe. How can I make it so this dataframe does not display every time the slider value is updated?

If I do something like:

```
r = interact(process_data, data=fixed(df), values=(1,5,1))
```

where "process_data" is my function. The result of "r" is *always* displayed right now. How can I stop this from happening? I want to save the dataframe "r" to use later.

Answer (score 2):

Set `__manual` to `True`:

```
r = interact(process_data, data=fixed(df), values=(1,5,1), __manual=True)
```

This gives you a button to click for executing your function.

Or, set `continuous_update=False`:

```
r = interact(process_data, data=fixed(df), values=(1,5,1),continuous_update=False))
```

to get the update only when you release the mouse button.

Comment: I still want the same functionality, I just don't want the results in r to always be displayed to screen automatically.